# Spark Broadcast join where 1.5 M records dataset needs to join with 150 records temp table

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm facing one issue where trying to join 1.5M records Dataset to another DF which is having 150 records. Performance is very bad and it's showing incorrect results. Can you please suggest broadcast join where LargeDF left join with small DF using Scala?

Thanks!

Comment: can you add schema for both datasets and sample data also

Comment: you can broadcast the 150 records as a suitable data-structure, for each partition of larger dataset rdd iterate each record and do a join yourself with broadcasted dataset, this would be more efficient then join

Comment: When joining with a small dataframe, Spark will automatically broadcast your small dataframe. It is called a Broadcast Hash Join. This is configurable via the `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` property. See  http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use the broadcast function explicitly, although as mentioned in the comments, spark should join automatically for small DFs.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.broadcast

dfBig.join(broadcast(dfSmall))
```